# Image is being blurred or pixelated while using Image.network in Flutter

Tags: flutter, image, dart

I am using Image.network in the code and wrapping that image in the boxConstraints for the even width of all the images and the height of image can be anything as per the network url. but the image is Getting Blurred as the screenshot below.

[Blurred Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxGjf.png)

I am expecting that image should be clear. but not working properly but when I am Extending the width of the image then it is working perfectly fine. I tried the anti alias property also but that too not worked I have shared the code below. Also This happens when I am running the applications in desktop but in android and iOS or mobile phones it is working fine.

```
class ImageMessage extends StatelessWidget {
  const ImageMessage({super.key, required this.imageUrl, required this.user});

  final String imageUrl;
  final User user;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        viewImage(context, imageUrl, imageUrl.split('/').last, user);
      },
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 4),
        child: Container(
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          child: ConstrainedBox(
            constraints: const BoxConstraints(minWidth: double.minPositive, maxWidth: 400),
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                  border: Border.all(width: 0.5, color: lightCustomColors.sourceGreypallet!)),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                child: ClipRRect(
                  clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                  child: Image.network(
                    imageUrl,
                    isAntiAlias: true,
                    filterQuality: FilterQuality.high,
                    scale: 1,
                    excludeFromSemantics: true,
                    //  height: 400,
                    width: 400,
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    loadingBuilder: (context, child, loadingProgress) {
                      return loadingProgress == null
                          ? child
                          : loadingProgress.cumulativeBytesLoaded < loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes!
                              ? SizedBox(
                                  width: 350,
                                  height: 200,
                                  child: Center(child: Utils.loadingWidget()),
                                )
                              : child;
                    },
                    errorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) {
                      return Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6), color: lightColorScheme.primaryContainer.withOpacity(0.5)),
                        width: 350,
                        height: 250,
                        child: const Center(
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Icon(
                                Iconsax.gallery_slash,
                                size: 20,
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 10,
                              ),
                              Text(
                                'Something Went Wrong!\nUnable to load image at the moment',
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the code of my Image Widget I am using